# Track new users source - Chrome Store extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a new extension that I am trying to get more users for, I am running two campaigns - lets call them A and B 
These campaigns eventually lead to my extension's page on the Chrome store. 
**Is there a way to know how much installs\addons did each campaign added? 
Not clicks - Proper users that added the extension.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes.

If you have enabled Google Analytics for your extensions (created a property and added it while editing the extension), that property will start tracking your Web Store page. If you haven't installed it, then no, no such refined data will be available.

You will see installs as visits to `/track_install/*` URLs. You can create a Goal to have better analytics for it, but you can probably dig through the data even without it.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I did enable GA as you specified

 can you please elaborate or point me to more specific location I found little info on using GA to track extension behaviour 
Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert in GA, sadly. As I saw your question, I checked my own analytics and noticed they tracked installs the way I described, via a special URL. You'll need to play around yourself to extract useful data, especially since I don't know specifics of your campaigns.

Comment: Can you please shed some light on what you did ?

Comment: Went to Analytics, randomly clicked things? I really can't provide further advice.

Comment: You would get more help by making a new question, tagged with [tag:google-analytics] + [tag:chrome-web-store], and explaining your campaigns a bit more. I set up my GA property for referrer lists only and don't know how to make more complicated things with it.

Comment: i track installs from campaigns using inline install. i dont think the campaign gets transfered all the way to the app store.